# .NET equivalent of httpunit

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I will openly admit that I fall on the side of Test Driven Development. I have run into a situation that I would like to test, but I haven't found a good way to do so.

I have been working in ASP.NET MVC and I would like to test that the parts of code that I am putting into the view layer (and I know that I need to keep that as minimal as possible). I am looking for an equivalent in .NET to httpunit in Java or something similar.

Comment: let me ask this, are you trying to test the logic that you have put in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can use HtmlUnit in .Net too: [Using HtmlUnit on .NET for Headless Browser Automation.](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/30/using-htmlunit-on-net-for-headless-browser-automation/)
The article contains links to other ways of UI testing too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)?

It is a generic web application testing system.

Another one is [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I make use of selenium. It is more geared to black box functional testing. The thing I like about httpunit/htmlunit and their ilk is they allow for more reliable direct testing of things that are difficult to do outside of the view layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something more lightweight, try SimpleBrowser for .Net - open sourced at Github. It doesn't support JavaScript, but that may not be a requirement for your needs.

https://github.com/axefrog/SimpleBrowser